# How to bind a DataTemplate item to a single entity in a navigational property

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I am working on a knowledgebase application which manages articles.

An article consists of a header (Id, Author ... etc.) and a set of text fragments, one of which contains the Title (TextType==2).

There is a listbox intended to display Id and Title but I have been unable correctly to bind the title to a textblock.

I have working code elsewhere to load a title entity

```
ArticleText te =  _header.ArticleTexts.Where(at => at.TextType == 2).FirstOrDefault();
```

so the property of the entity yielding the title would be `te.Body`

I set the ItemsSource of my listbox in code

```
public ObservableCollection<ArticleHeader> HeaderCollection
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<ArticleHeader>)articlesListBox.ItemsSource;
    }
    set
    {
        articlesListBox.ItemsSource = value;
    }
}
```

which correctly displays the Id but cannot seem to work out a way to bind to the (lazy loaded) title string.

My (simplified) xaml is as follows

```
        <ListBox Name="articlesListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                    </DockPanel> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I am aware there may be a number of solutions, but what is the next step ?

Answer (score 0):

Same as you did for ID?

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=Body}/>
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=Body.Title} />
```

Might have misunderstood your issue...

Comment: The title is held in a separate entity from the list of headers.  If I could do `Binding Path=ArticleTexts.Where(TextType==2)` that would be just peachy, but I can't

Answer (score 0):

The

```
ArticleTexts.Where(TextType==2)
```

part is something that should happen in your viewmodel/controller, not in XAML.

Instead of binding your ListBox to a collection of ArticleHeader objects you can create a new collection of anonymous objects that only hold the information you need (id and title), expose it as a property and bind your ListBox to that.

**Edit:**

There's always the alternative of using a BindingConverter, but that would entail creating a brand new class, which would be even more of a hassle than creating a new collection. Maybe you should add the solution you have in mind in your question and explicitly ask whether a better alternative exists.

Comment: This is how I am thinking now, although it is even simpler than that because I can easily retrieve a list of Titles.  This solution avoids answering the question though.  I have one method in mind to achieve what I asked, but was hoping for alternatives.

Comment: Looks like I was just doing that while you were typing.  You have put your finger on my REAL issue which is that what I want is a list of titles, rather than headers, but I am still interested to know if it is possible to bind to a single item in a navigational property.  You will see that the Converter was the solution I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help thinking there must be other (better) ways, but I was able to achieve what I asked by defining a value converter.

```
 [ValueConversion(typeof(ArticleHeader), typeof(String))]
    public class HeaderToTitleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ArticleHeader ah = value as ArticleHeader;

            ArticleText textEntity = null;

            using (KnowledgeManagementEntities ctx = KBContext.NewContext())
            {
                ctx.ArticleHeaders.Attach(ah);
                textEntity = ah.ArticleTexts.Where(at => at.TextType == KBConstants.TITLE_TYPE).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (textEntity == null)
                return "";

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textEntity.Body))
                return "";

            return textEntity.Body;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

Then in App.Xaml

```
<Application x:Class="SupportKB.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SupportKB" xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:SupportKB.Properties">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary> 
            <local:HeaderToTitleConverter x:Key="headerToTitleConverter" /> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

so the xaml now looks like this

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel Margin="0,2"> 
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="50" />
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
                   Margin="0,0,2,0" 
                   Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource headerToTitleConverter}}"/> 
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the end, though, I am going to rework the design so that a list of titles is master, and the headers are selected from that.

Comment: I try to use converters only as a last resort because they have a tendency to proliferate into a long list of classes. Then one day you realize that you just reimplemented the same converter because you had forgotten it already existed. But if it works for you, go for it.

Comment: I agree.  I am refactoring the application to run off a master list of titles.